# Updating a 'Link' field using the API

Tags: field, podio

I am trying to send a link via a python script, with description and thumbnail image via the API to a link field however the code I am trying only displays (in the link field) the raw link URL the raw link. The Python code I have is -

If this was the clickable box in the link field -

---

**someserver.com/somelink/somefile.txt**

someserver.com

---

```
send_data =
       { "fields":
                   { mylinkfield:
                                 { "type": "link",
                                    "title": "Books to read",
                                    "description": "I wish i could program better",
                                     "url": LINK_URL_VAR,
                                     "thumbnail": LOGO_URL_VAR
                                    }
                    }
          }
```

I keep trying different parameters and structures, but the only thing I can get is the raw URL to send to the field.

I did try reading through the documentation for the API but I'm still none the wiser.

And now I've hit a rate limit on Podio.
Any help, I'd greatly appreciate it.

I tried various combinations of parameters, then I hit a rate limit.
Neither worked.